# Errors when running custom SQL in Tableau：With clause and semicolon

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

As I create a custom SQL in Tableau. I ran into the following errors that I could never fix. (Both code chunks ran successfully in the SQL Management Studio)

```
With test as (SELECT DISTINCT
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Employee ID]+[vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Employee ID] as[ID_pair],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Framework] AS [Framework],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Last Name] AS [Observed Last Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed First Name] AS [Observed First Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[School] AS [School],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Last Name] AS [Observer Last Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer First Name] AS [Observer First Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Employee ID] AS [Observed Employee ID],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Employee ID] AS [Observer Employee ID],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Modified Date] AS [Modified Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Status] AS [Status],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Finalization/Completion Date] AS [Finalization/Completion Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Shared] AS [Shared],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Share Date] AS [Share Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observation Id] AS [Observation Id],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Rating Period] AS [Rating Period],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Questions] AS [Question],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Response] AS [Response]

FROM [dbo].[vw_PeerServeyDataDump] [vw_PeerServeyDataDump]
WHERE [Framework] = 'Peer Survey 2020-2021'),

test2 as (
Select Rank() OVER (Partition by [ID_pair] order by [Modified Date] DESC) as[Ranking],* 
From test)


Select *
From test2
Where Ranking=1
```

The followings are the errors:

> An error occurred while communicating with Microsoft SQL Server.
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
> near the keyword 'With'. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this
> statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a
> change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be
> terminated with a semicolon. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Then I have tried adding a semicolon before the with, it returns some other errors below:

```
;With test as (SELECT DISTINCT
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Employee ID]+[vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Employee ID] as[ID_pair],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Framework] AS [Framework],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Last Name] AS [Observed Last Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed First Name] AS [Observed First Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[School] AS [School],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Last Name] AS [Observer Last Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer First Name] AS [Observer First Name],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observed Employee ID] AS [Observed Employee ID],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observer Employee ID] AS [Observer Employee ID],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Modified Date] AS [Modified Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Status] AS [Status],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Finalization/Completion Date] AS [Finalization/Completion Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Shared] AS [Shared],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Share Date] AS [Share Date],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Observation Id] AS [Observation Id],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Rating Period] AS [Rating Period],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Questions] AS [Question],
  [vw_PeerServeyDataDump].[Response] AS [Response]

FROM [dbo].[vw_PeerServeyDataDump] [vw_PeerServeyDataDump]
WHERE [Framework] = 'Peer Survey 2020-2021'),

test2 as (
Select Rank() OVER (Partition by [ID_pair] order by [Modified Date] DESC) as[Ranking],* 
From test)


Select *
From test2
Where Ranking=1
```

> An error occurred while communicating with Microsoft SQL Server.
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
> near ';'. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Somebody, please help.

Comment: I think Tableau is going to want one select statement without a WITH

Comment: Try it with derived tables instead of CTEs

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer from the Tableau community.

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/unable-to-run-common-table-expressions-when-using-with-command

**Load in the cte in initial sql.**

Also, [another blog explaining a similar issue](https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/actually-you-can-use-variables-ctes-and-other-fancy-sql-with-tableau-after-all/)

Comment: ALSO, ANOTHER BLOG EXPLAINING SIMILAR ISSUE 
https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/actually-you-can-use-variables-ctes-and-other-fancy-sql-with-tableau-after-all/